# How to determine if the curve is closed

Tags: geometry, curves, differential

There is a given curve $ α(t) = (3 \cos t − \cos 3t, 3 \sin t − \sin 3t)$ and I have to determine if it's a closed one. I tried to find the answer and failed. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Cosine and Sine are $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: It is a closed one.

Comment: A good place to start would be to write down the definition of a "closed curve", then try to figure out if the parameterized curve you have described meets that definition.  It would also be helpful to know what you are studying, and what other tools (theorems, definitions, etc) you can use.  Finally, you say that you "tried to find the answer and failed."  What does that mean?  What attempt did you make?  Where did you get stuck?  Please provide context for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since this curve is periodic with a period $2\pi$, and it doesn't have any pole (any value of $t$ makes $\alpha(t)$ undefined), so after every $2\pi$ this curve will come back to the same point, and going to loop and loop with the same period infinitely, this curve is definitely closed. Hope this help!

Comment: Okay, so, the one thing confuses me. The sine function has the $ 2 \pi $ period, and after every $ 2 \pi $ is comes to the same point, and yet it's not closed.

Comment: @nergal26 The sine function is not a curve.  It is a function.

Comment: What a mistake. Everything is clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With $\alpha(t)= (3\cos t−\cos 3t, 3\sin t−\sin 3t)$ we see
$$\alpha(0)=(2,0)=\alpha(2\pi)$$
shows this path is closed in $[0,2\pi]$. Indeed since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic, then $3\cos t−\cos 3t$ and $3\sin t−\sin 3t$ are also peridic with period $2\pi$ then in every interval $[t_0,t_0+2\pi]$ we have $\alpha(t_0)=\alpha(t_0+2\pi)$.